# ZMQ high water mark deprecated on 3.x.x?

Tags: scala, zeromq, jzmq

Using the jzmq wrapper:

scala> import org.zeromq.ZMQ
import org.zeromq.ZMQ

```
scala> val context = ZMQ.context(1)
context: org.zeromq.ZMQ.Context = org.zeromq.ZMQ$Context@56d58984

scala> val socket = context.socket(ZMQ.REP)
socket: org.zeromq.ZMQ.Socket = org.zeromq.ZMQ$Socket@2a5a0f9

scala> socket.getHWM()
res6: Long = -1

scala> socket.setHWM(200)

scala> socket.getHWM()
res8: Long = -1
```

This seems to be depreacted in version 3:

https://github.com/zeromq/jzmq/blob/750f2eecaa4c71adf86c156fab5840a2f614d4ea/src/org/zeromq/ZMQ.java#L895-900

Anyone knows why? and what's the alternative to set a HWM using jzqm + zmq3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at: http://zeromq.org/docs:3-1-upgrade

In zeromq 3.2 HWM has been split into send and receive high water mark: `ZMQ_SNDHWM` and `ZMQ_RCVHWM`.

The functions you are looking for in jzmq are:

```
long    getRcvHWM()
long    getSndHWM()
void    setRcvHWM(long rcvHWM)
void    setSndHWM(long sndHWM)
```

Answer (score 2):

The CZMQ binding simulates the old HWM option, and other bindings might do the same.